# How can I place a div below a navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to place a div below my top navbar which should not scroll with the page content just like the navbar.

I've tried to create it as a second navbar but it is still scrolling or causing a blank area above the two navbars.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

In this sample the green bar is on top of the navbar, but I need it to stay below the navbar: http://jsfiddle.net/julianonunes/y8YqK/

If I move the green bar code (code sample below) before the navbar, it is hidden by the navbar.

Ex:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-decoration navbar-fixed-top"></div>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-remote navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  The problem is your second div includes 'navbar-fixed-top' which is glueing it to the top of your screen.  You don't want it fixed to the top - you just want it fixed in place below the main navbar.  Change your html for the second nag to:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-remote navbar-decoration ">
```

And add to your navbar-decoration class:

```
width: 100%
position: fixed;
```

Comment: Is that not what you want?

Comment: There's a space between the div and navbar, however I got rid of this space by using margin-top: -10px;. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have tried this already, but in the css for the second navbar put

```
position: fixed;
```

If you don't want to add to your stylesheet, you can put it in the div like this:

```
<div style="position: fixed;"> </div>
```

I am not sure, but you may also have to add display:block like this:

```
<div style="position: fixed; display: block;"> </div>
```

With Bootstrap, use this logic within their html/css:

```
<div class="navbar" style="position: fixed; display: block;">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

My last guess:

```
<div class="navbar" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope one of those works.

Comment: It didn't work. I'm creating a jsfiddle to help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it fixed by adding margin-top to the second navbar with navbar-fixed-top.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-remote navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-decoration navbar-fixed-top"></div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-decoration {
    margin-top: 50px;
    min-height: 5px;
    max-height: 5px;
/* ... */
}
```